# The Error of His Ways

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Problem: A student claims that x-1 is not irreducible because $x-1 = (\sqrt{x} -1)(\sqrt{x} + 1)$. Explain the error of his ways.
>
> Definition: An element $p$ in a domain $R$ is irreducible if $p$ is neither $0$ nor a unit and, in every factorization $p=uv$, either $u$ or $v$ is a unit.

It's hard to say what's wrong. The problem doesn't specify how we are to interpret the symbols. Are we working $\Bbb{Z}[x]$? $\Bbb{Q}[x]$? $\Bbb{R}[x]$? Or perhaps $\Bbb{Z}_n[x]$? Does the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ even make sense in any of those settings?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense until you explain what $x$ is. Are you talking about $\mathbb R[x]$?

Comment: One problem is that $\sqrt{x}$ isn't a polynomial by anyone's definition.

Comment: You two are asking the wrong person. I typed the problem exactly as it is.

Comment: @user193319 Well, in a sense we *are* explaining part of the problem with the student's question! The lack of clarity of context, the assumption that $\sqrt{x}$ is an element of the ring are two major problems.

Comment: @Randall That's what I was thinking. Perhaps this is the student's error.

Comment: As long as $R$ is an integral domain, it is true that $x - 1$ is irreducible in $R[x]$ (if it weren't it would be the product of two polynomials of smaller degree, which is impossible because they would be constant). A counterexample in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ would be $x - 1 = (2x - 1)(2x^2 + x + 1)$.

Comment: Actually he is right, if we allow ourself to consider $\sqrt x$ to be the variable.

Comment: So $7$ isn't prime, since $7=\sqrt7\sqrt7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if we're working in a ring where $\sqrt x$ makes sense, the student's argument will only work if he *also* argues that neither $\sqrt x - 1$ nor $\sqrt x + 1$ is a unit in that ring.

Since we don't know what the ring is, it's possible that he can in fact do that (that would be the case if the ring is $\mathbb R[\sqrt x]$, for example) -- but it is still *his error* that he is not *providing* that argument.

Answer (score 1):

If we are indeed working in a polynomial ring, then I think you are correct that the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ makes no sense in this setting.

More generally (as you pointed out), what do we mean when we say that a polynomial of degree greater than one is irreducible?  It may be reducible over $\mathbf R$ but not over $\mathbf Q$.  And it'll always be reducible over $\mathbf C$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.